# Solr: Avoid duplicated records while importing from another solr core

Tags: solr, dih

I am trying to import a single column from a solr core into another core using DIH. Solr version is 6.4.0

My managed-schema file has the following entries:

```
<uniqueKey>journal</uniqueKey>
<field name="journal" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="fjournal" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

and also one copyField settings like below:

```
<copyField source="journal" dest="fjournal" />
```

In the solrconfig.xml, i configured the following elements:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler>
    <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
 </requestHandler>

<updateRequestProcessorChain>
    <processor class="solr.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">journal</str>
    </processor>

    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

And the following is in the file "solr-data-config.xml"

```
<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="journalMaster" processor="SolrEntityProcessor"
            url="http://localhost:8983/solr/journalMaster "
            query="*:*"
            fl="journal"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I execute the import process, the values after the import has been completed, still holds the duplicated values.

```
 {    "journal":"Journal of Immunology",
        "_version_":1559554209274134528,
        "fjournal":"Journal of Immunology"},
      {
        "journal":"Journal of Immunology",
        "_version_":1559554209373749248,
        "fjournal":"Journal of Immunology"},
      {
        "journal":"Journal of Immunology",
        "_version_":1559554209375846400,
        "fjournal":"Journal of Immunology"},
```

How do I avoid this from happening? I am importing the data from a local core to another core.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a TextField for the uniqueKey-field - try to use a string field for the uniqueKey, and then copy it into the textfield instead. The UniqFieldsUpdateProcessor also only works with the values inside a multivalued field in the current document - not between documents.

Comment: Hi MatsLind, thanks for the info. I will try out your given suggestion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a uniqueKey you don't need to analyse the content.
Just have a string that will uniquely identify the documents.
This unique identifier will be used across a lot of different Lucene/Solr functionality, so it is important to define it properly.

In your example I would use 'fjournal' as the unique key.

Then, there is nothing else to worry about, everytime you re-index the same fjournal, the Solr document will be overwritten, so you will end up with a single entry per value.

Probably a better curiousity would be to know why you need to index a single fielded document ...

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the journal column to be of type string and removed the other column.

Comment: Why I had to go for a single indexed column here, is that, I need only unique values of this particular column from the main core. That core holds more than 10M records with more duplicated entries for this field. I tried faceting on the same column in the main core, but since it was defined "text_general" I was just getting tokenized counts in the facet query. So I planned to get only the values from the column into a new core but indexed, so that it wont duplicate.

Comment: Hi Lazar,
what I would have done, is to set a copy field for the journal field, configured as a string type.
Then, in the original collection you could use faceting on this new field ( that will have the same content of the source, but not analysed ).
When faceting you can play with the facet limit parameter to see how many unique values you like ( with the related count of occurrences)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for the suggestion. If you do not mind, can you share a sample for the faceting limit option. With your previous suggestion, i was able to get the unique values and the required core got created. Thanks once again for helping out.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.limitParameter

This is the official documentation.
Hope it helps!